# Git revert back and append changes

Tags: git, git-revert

In multiple script files, certain lines were replaced with new ones.
In git it looks like that:

```
- Write-Host "Something went wrong" -ForegroundColor Red
+ Custom-LoggingFunction "Something went wrong" -ErrorAction Stop
```

The branch is now dozens of commits ahead.

I would like to have both of the lines now - the Custom-LoggingFunction lines and the ones that were removed - Write-Host ones.

If I simply revert, I will loose all current changes.
What would be the most optimal solution in that case?

Comment: Way off topic of your Git question, but you might be able to change `Custom-LoggingFunction` to also do the `Write-Host` part, instead of keeping both lines. Perhaps even make it a parameter so the caller can decide whether or not to also `Write-Host`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a revert --no-commit

```
git revert --no-commit whatever
```

Then work with your IDE to select what you would like to keep when comparing with HEAD... that's what I do in these cases.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one good option if you are working with a good modern IDE such as IntelliJ or XCode.  You may choose from the IDE to compare a given script file against an earlier revision having the original `Write-Host` lines.  The diff tool should show you both versions, original and new.  From there, you may copy and paste the now deleted lines over to the latest version.

Comment: I agree it's straight forward and I use it often.

Comment: What I find a little bit annoying in IntelliJ is that you can compare with either other _branches_.... or **ancestors**..... it's not possible to use a commit from another  branch.... it would require creating a temporary branch just for that. A `temp` branch is always handy, if you ask me... but still.

Comment: @eftshift0 Your observation is correct, and it is a limitation of IntelliJ.

Comment: @eftshift0 Visual Studio is the same way, and you also can't even do branches. I (used to) just stay on my current branch and `git merge -s ours other-branch` so it shows up in the view, then I do the compare and reset hard right back. That saves 10-20 seconds compared to making a new branch... (Now I use VSCode anytime I want to view multiple branches in the same graph for compares.)